# Colored Line plots of different variables with missing values in one figure using R

Tags: r, time-series, lapply

Here is an example data to proceed for my problem (the number of variables are large in reality)

```
date<-seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12)
v1<-seq(2,32, length.out=12)
v2<-c(11,NA,30,NA,NA,35,NA,40,48,NA,55,64)
v3<-c(5,NA,NA,NA,22,25,NA,30,NA,NA,45,NA)
as.POSIXlt(date, format="%Y/%m/%d")
df<-data.frame(date, v1, v2, v3)
```

To plot all variables at once with time, I'm using:

```
matplot(df[,1], df[2:ncol(df)], type='p', pch=2:4, col=2:4)
```

Now I want to connect all points through lines, but 'matlines' can't interpolate where missing values occur. I didn't use type='b' in 'matplot' because it plots continuous line only for v1 (i.e. continuous data).

However, one way to interpolate is to use 'approx' function. So I tried

```
matplot(approx(df[,1], df[2:ncol(df)], n= length(df[[1]])), type='p', pch=2:4, col=2:4)
```

But R throws an error: "`Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`"

Now as the last resort, I tried 'lapply' to superimpose lines over symbol, but in this case, different colors doesn't show up for different variables!!

```
lapply(2:4, function(i) lines(
  approx(df[,1],
         df[[i]], n= length(df[[1]])),
  lty=2, col=2:4))
```

Is there any other way to plot the variables as lines + symbols with different colors in a single figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution using `ggplot`

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# melt the data frame df from wide format (three columns V1-V3 with values on the same measured variable)
# to long format (one column "variable" with three different levels, and one "value" with the measurements)
df2 <- melt(df, id.vars = "date")

# remove rows with missing "value"
df3 <- df2[!is.na(df2$value), ]

# plot value ~ date, coloured by 'variable'
ggplot(data = df3, aes(x = date, y = value, col = variable)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `col=2:4` with `col=i` in your call to `lapply()` (last code block) you will get lines of the correct color in your plot.

The error with `approx()` is pretty self-explanatory -- the `x` and `y` arguments need to be vectors, and you are providing a data.frame for `y`. Use `approx()` separately for each column, and it works fine.

```
df_approx = matrix(nrow = nrow(df), ncol = 3)
for(i in 2:4) df_approx[,i-1] = approx(df[,1], df[,i], n=length(df[[1]]) )$y
matplot(df[,1], df_approx)
```